# What is the font name used in this design

Tags: font-identification, font-recommendation

I have been searching the font name using a couple of services like Fontspring Matcherator, WhatTheFont! and Photoshop CC. Alas, I'm not able to find the name of the font. Can someone please identify this font? I would appreciate your help!

The text written by this font is: "S.Walkowiak"

[image]

Comment: There's a possibility it's an *actual* signature or a signature which was manually created to reflect real-world scribbling and not a font. Many designers will not simply pick a font for someone's signature. I, myself, will **never** use any font to mimic a signature. I'll sign the name myself on a piece of paper and scan that before I use a font.

Comment: If WhatTheFont couldn't figure it out automatically, you could submit it to the forum there.  The "W" in this sample looks familiar to me.

Comment: If it is a font, which is not certain, there are many script fonts, and automatic font ID sites don't work well with these kind of fonts. You might be better looking through lists of fonts, such as those on [dafont](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603&text=S.Walkowiak&fpp=200) - there's only around 14,000 or so to search through. You might find it, or something similar at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like this font
Luxembourg Signature

https://www.creativefabrica.com/product/luxembourg-signature/ref/166515/

Comment: Yea, thank you, it's that font!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an actual signature. The "k" and "a" letterforms are very similar, but still different.

Comment: The baseline seems too consistent to be actual handwriting.  The "k" and "a" actually look almost identical to me, I could chalk up any differences to a sloppy scan.